# How do I kill sidekiq worker when it reaches memory threshold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Currently my sidekiq is reaching memory threshold very often. I am making some changes in my process under sidekiq to reduce time taken for completion of task. But in meantime I would like to know if there is any way where I can gracefully kill my sidekiq worker process when it reaches some predefined memory limit and then restart it.

Answer (score 1):

Find the parent process pid using the command

```
ps aux | grep sidekiq
```

Then issue USR1 signal to the parent process. This will let the children serve the current requests and then kill them

```
kill -USR1 <pid>
```

And then start your sidekiq like how you would normally start

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MMonit](http://mmonit.com/), a Unix monitoring system where you can define conditions over each proocess and actions to be taken like (start, stop or restart the process) when the conditions are satisfied.

Example:

```
check process apache with pidfile /var/run/httpd.pid
       start program = "/etc/init.d/httpd start"
       stop program  = "/etc/init.d/httpd stop"
       if cpu > 40% for 2 cycles then alert
       if totalcpu > 60% for 2 cycles then alert
       if totalcpu > 80% for 5 cycles then restart
       if mem > 100 MB for 5 cycles then stop
       if loadavg(5min) greater than 10.0 for 8 cycles then stop
```

If you are automating your infrastructure with Chef, there is a mmonit cookbook which simplifies mmonit considerably.

**UPDATE**: I found a Railscast (pro) about Monit, http://railscasts.com/episodes/375-monit.